# PHP: Birthday check today´s date

Tags: php

I have user´s birthday stored in `birthday` as 1999-02-26.

How can I check if the birthday is today?

```
if(date('m-d') == ..?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(date('m-d') == substr($birthday,5,5))
```

To add what Tim said:

```
if(date('m-d') == substr($birthday,5,5) or (date('y')%4 <> 0 and substr($birthday,5,5)=='02-29' and date('m-d')=='02-28'))
```

Comment: You should also allow for Ted's birthday on 2004-02-29 - in 2011, he will celebrate his birthday on 02-28.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I have changed in the answer.

Comment: Great. Although I don't think you need to check `date('y')%4` because a. that rule isn't quite correct, and b. the validation whether a certain date is valid at all should have been done when that date was entered.

Comment: @Tim: with that check date('y')%4 I an searching for a leap year (last 2 digits of a year must devide with 4 to be a leap year).

Comment: That rule is wrong, though. 1900 wasn't a leap year, for example. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year (and anyway, part b. of my comment still applies. If you haven't validated the birthday on input, what's to keep someone from entering 31-06-1950 or 99-99-9999 as their birthday?)

Answer (score 13):

This answer *should* work, but it depends on [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) being able to figure out your database's date format:

```
$birthDate = '1999-02-26'; // Read this from the DB instead
$time = strtotime($birthDate);
if(date('m-d') == date('m-d', $time)) {
    // They're the same!
}
```

Comment: _Should_ is not enough in this complicated world. Those date and time calculation always tend to have hidden difficulties at different edges and occurrences. It is very hard to check birthday for somebody born at 29 February. And checking for leap years is complicated. This deserves some ready solution.

Comment: @German Well, strtotime is written by a third party...  Incidentally, I noticed I'd accidentally linked to strptime's manual page when I wrote this... which is a different function.   Incidentally, since this answer was written, PHP had DateTime objects and related functions added to it.

Comment: If you check the output for both then they will match when you compare.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
/**
 * @param string $birthday Y-m-d
 * @param int $now
 * @return bool
 */
function birthdayToday($birthday, $now = null) {
    $birthday = substr($birthday, -5);
    if ($now === null) {
        $now = time();
    }
    $today = date('m-d', $now);
    return $birthday == $today || $birthday == '02-29' && $today == '02-28' && !checkdate(2, 29, date('Y', $now));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this one

```
$birthday = new DateTime("05-28-2020");
$today = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));

if ($birthday->format("m-d") == $today->format("m-d")) {
 echo 'Today is your birthday';
} else {
 echo 'Today is not your birthday';
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on Stack Overflow.  Please explain how your answer differs from pre-existing answers and why you advise researchers to use this technique.  Every answer should contain an explanation with the intention of educating/empowering thousands of future researchers.  I personally never upvote code-only answers -- even if they are 100% correct -- because that would only encourage more code-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP 5.2 upwards:

```
if (substr($dateFromDb, -5) === date_create()->format('m-d')) {
    // Happy birthday!
}
```